# Tuple contains tow list in c#

Tags: c#

I want to create a function with c# who return for me a list of ip and port the function is like that:

```
public Tuple<string,int> loadSocks()
{
    var listip = new List<string>();
    var listprt = new List<int>();
    var input = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Exploit1/socks-list.txt"));
    var r = new Regex(@"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d{1,5})");
    foreach (Match match in r.Matches(input))
    {
        string ip = match.Groups[1].Value;
        int port =  Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[2].Value);
        listip.Add(ip);
        listprt.Add(port);
        Tuple<List<string>, List<int>> tplLst = new Tuple<List<string>, List<int>>(listip, listprt);
        Tuple<string, int> tplSum = Add(tplLst);

    }
    return tplLst;
}
```

I use tuple , I add tow list in this tuple but he give me the error in  Tuple tplSum = Add(tplLst); in Add(tplLst).

What I should do ?

Comment: what does "Add(tplLst)" do?

Comment: @ wudzik  he add the tuple who containe tow list to another tuple who is tplSum  in my function

Comment: This question doesn't contain all information necessary to help you; If you report an error, of course give us a whole copy of the error.

Also, your title is very bad. The fact that you wrote "probleme" instead of "problem" shows that you ran into StackOverflows automated system of detecting Titles that tell nothing about the problem underneath. Try to more closely find out what the problem is, then ask a precise question. You'll get much better answers that way!

Comment: @vc 74 no bro i do that but always the same problem

Comment: @Marcus Müller  thnks bro

Comment: @CatSteven: with all due respect, I'm not your bro.

Comment: I've had a look at your other questions. You don't have a single question with a non-negative score. Don't you notice your questions need improvement? **Please** read the help pages on how to ask good questions. You're actively making it hard for us to help you, and by doing so, you're decreasing average SO question quality.

Comment: @Marcus Müller i want to remove all bad question in my profile, the probleme that i have i m not good in english my english is very very bad, for that people dont understand what i want

Comment: @CatSteven: it's not your English. Your English is fine, really. You just don't put much effort in asking a question, providing all the info necessary, formatting the things, etc.

Comment: @Marcus Müller thanks , i try in the futur to not repeat the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to simplfy your code. Instead of using a tuple which often decrease readability I would create a type for your purpose.

```
public class BiningInfo
{

    public IPAddress IpAddress { get; set;}

    public int Port { get; set;} 

}


public List<BiningInfo> loadSocks()
{
    var result = new List<BiningInfo>();

    var input = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Exploit1/socks-list.txt"));
    var r = new Regex(@"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d{1,5})");
    foreach (Match match in r.Matches(input))
    {
        string ip = match.Groups[1].Value;
        int port =  Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[2].Value);

        BiningInfo bi = new BiningInfo();
        bi.IpAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
        bi.Port = port;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: i dont understand public IpAddress IpAddress { get; set;}

    public int Port Port { get; set;}  this properties i create a new class IpAddress  and class Port

Comment: @C Sharper can you please add some comment in the code

Comment: Sorry, I did some typo, I updated the code. The .NET Framework has a class IPAddress (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress(v=vs.110).aspx). The `Port` property is an `int`.

Comment: he give me error in bi = IPAddress.Parse(ip); he dont say IPAddress

Comment: Sorry again :D I updated the code. Thanks for finding this mistake.

Comment: thnks bro, another help please , what i should do if iwant to do a boucle in the main who give me always a new ip and his port

Comment: This is out of scope of this post, please feel free to setup a new question on SO. If my answer satisfied your question, accept it as valid.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've got your point. I think the following code is what you're looking for :

```
public List<Tuple<string, int>> loadSocks()
{
    List<Tuple<string, int>> result = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
    var input = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Exploit1/socks-list.txt"));
    var r = new Regex(@"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d{1,5})");
    foreach (Match match in r.Matches(input))
    {
        string ip = match.Groups[1].Value;
        int port = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[2].Value);
        result.Add(new Tuple<string,int>(ip,port));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: it work fine bro , how to do for Call function for return me one ip and his port

Comment: @CatSteven you can return a list with one item. result[0].Item1 & item2

Comment: @ Mohammad Chamanpara  if i want to do a boucle that he give me all the time a new ip and his port what i should do my bro

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to return a **list of tuples**. Change the signature of your function to return a list. Initialize a variable to hold the result. Then add each ip/port combination to it. Finally return the result.

```
public List<Tuple<string,int>> loadSocks()
{
    var result = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();

    var input = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Exploit1/socks-list.txt"));
    var r = new Regex(@"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d{1,5})");

    foreach (Match match in r.Matches(input))
    {
        string ip = match.Groups[1].Value;
        int port =  Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[2].Value);

        result.Add(new Tuple<string,int>(ip, port));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: if i want to do a boucle that he give me all the time a new ip and his port what i should do my bro